# Maven Project creation Issue in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I am trying to create a new Maven Project in eclipse but I keep getting this error all the time.

```
Invalid project description.
OK
A Link location must be specified.
```

I am trying to create a new Maven Project (Create Simple Project) and providing below details:

```
Group ID
Artifact Id
version
Packaging
Name
Description
```

Is there some issue with my Maven plugin in Eclipse ?

Comment: Better solution create maven porject with commandline (cmd) but I use sometimes eclipse too.
new ->project->maven->maven project
now select checkbox "Create a simple project(skip archetype selection)
fill in Artifact panel: groupId, ArtifactId, verision (if you wish) and select packing jar or war. Panel Parent project leave empty. Now button Finish and should be project created. If not try reintall maven project.

Comment: try by cmd.  command:
`mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=packages.of.your.project -DartifactId=projectName -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false`
and import this project to eclipse as maven project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Make sure you select Create simple project and edit advanced option to link existing projects.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an older post, but I was/am also running into this issue when creating Maven projects in Eclipse.

I believe it may stem from the default workspace where eclipse wants to store the Maven project. When I try to create a new project, it wants to put it in an existing folder on a project directory I was currently in.

What I did was just restart eclipse and went to add a Maven project. In the default workspace in the wizard, it was blank (which was good). From there, as long as that default workspace is blank and not showing any other project directory, I am able to create a Maven project without that invalid description error.

Edit: I am using Maven version 3.5.2

[Image of new Maven Project with blank default workspace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhKPr.png)

Comment: Please add your Maven version for which you use this answer.

Comment: Ancient post... but this saved me. I encountered this issue in Eclipse 2022-03

Answer (score 3):

Try building a new dynamic web project ,then right click ->configure ->convert to maven project ! It works

Answer (score 1):

Must create a empty java project firstly then to create maven project.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was actually creating an empty folder to store the project in, then browsing for it in the location bar.  Even if you don't check the second box in the wizard (which I did not), having that location was what allowed me to create the project.

[Wizard configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZ8t1.png)

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse has a problem when trying to access your default workspace where it wants to store your new Maven project.
To avoid this error, make sure you clear the [the default path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnSgA.png), just leave it blank.
Make sure that you are crossing `"Use default workspace location"`. This will do the work.

Answer (score 0):

Check if there is any space at both the ends. In My case there was a space at the end of the project name which was causing this issue.